# XSLT Validation using for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to write logic for an XSLT Validation Template to check an XML message for a  repeating loop for various conditions.

The structure of the message is

```
<VXU_V04.ORDER> One or more may be present, not a required group; I’m calling this “OrderGroup”
<ORC> Required; only one ORC Segment per OrderGroup allowed
<ORC.3> Required; only one ORC.3 field per ORC Segment allowed
<EI.1>, <EI.2>, <EI.3> and <EI.4> are sub-components of ORC.3
```

These four fields have their own validations that I need to code for.  There will only be one ORC.3 per ORC Segment and only one set of EI sub-components for each ORC.3.  However, I do still have the concept of multiple ORC segments within an Order Group to account for, so I still need to use the for-each construct to account for multiple ORC segments.

Here is my validation template for ORC.3:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:a="urn:hl7-org:v2xml" xmlns:dil="http://www.aegis.net/msg/filter/jaxb/rule" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!--      
         Must be VALUED AND 
         Must not repeat
         -->
    <xsl:variable name="OrderGroup" select="/a:VXU_V04/a:VXU_V04.ORDER"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ORCSegment" select="/a:VXU_V04/a:VXU_V04.ORDER/a:ORC"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ORC3Field" select="/a:VXU_V04/a:VXU_V04.ORDER/a:ORC/a:ORC.3"/>
    <xsl:variable name="EI1Field" select="/a:VXU_V04/a:VXU_V04.ORDER/a:ORC/a:ORC.3/a:EI.1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="EI2Field" select="/a:VXU_V04/a:VXU_V04.ORDER/a:ORC/a:ORC.3/a:EI.2"/>
    <xsl:variable name="EI3Field" select="/a:VXU_V04/a:VXU_V04.ORDER/a:ORC/a:ORC.3/a:EI.3"/>
    <xsl:variable name="EI4Field" select="/a:VXU_V04/a:VXU_V04.ORDER/a:ORC/a:ORC.3/a:EI.4"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <dil:filterruleresult>
             <xsl:choose>
                 <xsl:when test= "count($OrderGroup)= 0">
                    <dil:message type="info">VXU Order Group not found.</dil:message>
                 </xsl:when>
             </xsl:choose>
             <xsl:for-each select="$OrderGroup">
                     <xsl:choose>
                       <xsl:when test="count(a:ORC)= 0">  
                          <dil:message type="error">When Order Group present, ORC Segment is required.</dil:message>
                       </xsl:when>
                       <xsl:when test="count(a:ORC)> 1">  
                        <dil:message type="error">Only one Order Segment (ORC) allowed per Order Group.</dil:message>
                       </xsl:when>
                       <xsl:otherwise>
                          <xsl:for-each select="a:ORC">
                             <xsl:choose>
                                 <xsl:when test="count(a:ORC.3)= 0">
                                    <dil:message type="error">ORC-3 Filler Order Number not found but is required.</dil:message>
                                 </xsl:when> 
                                 <xsl:when test="count(a:ORC.3)> 1">
                                     <dil:message type="error">Only one Filler Order Number (ORC-3) allowed per Order Segment.</dil:message>
                                 </xsl:when> 
                                 <xsl:when test="count(a:EI.1)> 1">
                                     <dil:message type="error">When present, only one Filler Order Number (ORC-3) allowed per Order Segment.</dil:message>
                                 </xsl:when> 
                                 <xsl:when test="count(a:EI.1)= 0">
                                     <dil:message type="error">When Filler Order Number Present, Entity Identifier (ORC-3/EI-1) is required.</dil:message>
                                 </xsl:when>
                                  <xsl:when test="count(a:EI.3)= 0 and count(a:EI.2)= 0">
                                     <dil:message type="error">When Filler Order Number Present, Namespace ID (ORC-3/EI-2) or Universal ID (ORC-3/EI-3) is required.</dil:message>
                                 </xsl:when>  
                                 <xsl:when test="count(a:EI.3)= 1 and count(a:EI.4)= 0">
                     <dil:message type="error">When Filler Order Number Universal ID is present, Universal ID Type (ORC-3/EI-4) is required.</dil:message>
                                 </xsl:when>
                                 <xsl:when test="count(a:EI.3)= 0 and count(a:EI.4)= 0">
                     <dil:message type="error">When Filler Order Number Universal ID is not present, Universal ID Type (ORC-3/EI-4) is not supported.</dil:message>
                                 </xsl:when> 
                                 <xsl:when test="count(a:ORC.3)= 1">
                                     <dil:message type="info">Value of '<xsl:value-of select="./a:EI.1"/>', '<xsl:value-of select="./a:EI.2"/>', '<xsl:value-of select="./a:EI.3"/>', '<xsl:value-of select="./a:EI.4"/>' found for Filler Order Number (ORC-2).</dil:message>
                                 </xsl:when>
                             </xsl:choose>
                          </xsl:for-each>  
                       </xsl:otherwise>
                      </xsl:choose> 
             </xsl:for-each>      
        </dil:filterruleresult>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that the template is not finding my EI fields at all.  I keep getting stuck at the error "When Filler Order Number Present, Entity Identifier (ORC-3/EI-1) is required." but I do have EI-1 values in my test message.

Here is the relevant portion of my test message:

```
  <VXU_V04.ORDER>
    <ORC>
      <ORC.1>RE</ORC.1>
      <ORC.3>
        <EI.1>197023</EI.1>
        <EI.2>DCS</EI.2>
      </ORC.3>
      <ORC.10>
        <XCN.2>
          <FN.1>Clerk</FN.1>
        </XCN.2>
        <XCN.3>Myron</XCN.3>
      </ORC.10>
      <ORC.17>
        <CE.1>DCS</CE.1>
        <CE.2>Dabig Clinical System</CE.2>
        <CE.3>StateIIS</CE.3>
      </ORC.17>
    </ORC>
    <RXA>
      <RXA.1>0</RXA.1>
      <RXA.2>1</RXA.2>
      <RXA.3>
        <TS.1>20090415132511</TS.1>
      </RXA.3>
      <RXA.4>
        <TS.1>20090415132511</TS.1>
      </RXA.4>
      <RXA.5>
        <CE.1>31</CE.1>
        <CE.2>Hep B Peds NOS</CE.2>
        <CE.3>CVX</CE.3>
      </RXA.5>
      <RXA.6>999</RXA.6>
      <RXA.9>
        <CE.1>01</CE.1>
        <CE.2>historical record</CE.2>
        <CE.3>NIP0001</CE.3>
      </RXA.9>
    </RXA>
  </VXU_V04.ORDER>
  <VXU_V04.ORDER>
    <ORC>
      <ORC.1>RE</ORC.1>
      <ORC.3>
        <EI.1>197027</EI.1>
        <EI.2>DCS</EI.2>
      </ORC.3>
      <ORC.10>
        <XCN.2>
          <FN.1>Clerk</FN.1>
        </XCN.2>
        <XCN.3>Myron</XCN.3>
      </ORC.10>
      <ORC.12>
        <XCN.2>
          <FN.1>Pediatric</FN.1>
        </XCN.2>
        <XCN.3>MARY</XCN.3>
        <XCN.10>L</XCN.10>
        <XCN.21>MD</XCN.21>
      </ORC.12>
    </ORC>
    <RXA>
      <RXA.1>0</RXA.1>
      <RXA.2>1</RXA.2>
      <RXA.3>
        <TS.1>20090531132511</TS.1>
      </RXA.3>
      <RXA.4>
        <TS.1>20090531132511</TS.1>
      </RXA.4>
      <RXA.5>
        <CE.1>48</CE.1>
        <CE.2>HIB PRP-T</CE.2>
        <CE.3>CVX</CE.3>
      </RXA.5>
      <RXA.6>999</RXA.6>
      <RXA.9>
        <CE.1>00</CE.1>
        <CE.2>new Immunization record</CE.2>
        <CE.3>NIP0001</CE.3>
      </RXA.9>
      <RXA.10>
        <XCN.2>
          <FN.1>Sticker</FN.1>
        </XCN.2>
        <XCN.3>Nurse</XCN.3>
      </RXA.10>
      <RXA.11>
        <LA2.4>
          <HD.1>DCS_DC</HD.1>
        </LA2.4>
      </RXA.11>
      <RXA.15>33k2a</RXA.15>
      <RXA.17>
        <CE.1>PMC</CE.1>
        <CE.2>sanofi</CE.2>
        <CE.3>MVX</CE.3>
      </RXA.17>
    </RXA>
    <RXR>
      <RXR.1>
        <CE.1>C28161</CE.1>
        <CE.2>IM</CE.2>
        <CE.3>NCIT</CE.3>
        <CE.4>IM</CE.4>
        <CE.5>IM</CE.5>
        <CE.6>HL70162</CE.6>
      </RXR.1>
    </RXR>
  </VXU_V04.ORDER>
  <VXU_V04.ORDER>
    <ORC>
      <ORC.1>RE</ORC.1>
      <ORC.3>
        <EI.1>197028</EI.1>
        <EI.2>DCS</EI.2>
      </ORC.3>
      <ORC.10>
        <XCN.2>
          <FN.1>Clerk</FN.1>
        </XCN.2>
        <XCN.3>Myron</XCN.3>
      </ORC.10>
      <ORC.12>
        <XCN.2>
          <FN.1>Pediatric</FN.1>
        </XCN.2>
        <XCN.3>MARY</XCN.3>
        <XCN.10>L</XCN.10>
        <XCN.21>MD</XCN.21>
      </ORC.12>
    </ORC>
    <RXA>
      <RXA.1>0</RXA.1>
      <RXA.2>1</RXA.2>
      <RXA.3>
        <TS.1>20090531132511</TS.1>
      </RXA.3>
      <RXA.4>
        <TS.1>20090531132511</TS.1>
      </RXA.4>
      <RXA.5>
        <CE.1>110</CE.1>
        <CE.2>DTAP-Hep B-IPV</CE.2>
        <CE.3>CVX</CE.3>
      </RXA.5>
      <RXA.6>999</RXA.6>
      <RXA.9>
        <CE.1>00</CE.1>
        <CE.2>new immunization record</CE.2>
        <CE.3>NIP0001</CE.3>
      </RXA.9>
      <RXA.10>
        <XCN.2>
          <FN.1>Sticker</FN.1>
        </XCN.2>
        <XCN.3>Nurse</XCN.3>
      </RXA.10>
      <RXA.11>
        <LA2.4>
          <HD.1>DCS_DC</HD.1>
        </LA2.4>
      </RXA.11>
      <RXA.15>xy3939</RXA.15>
      <RXA.17>
        <CE.1>SKB</CE.1>
        <CE.2>GSK</CE.2>
        <CE.3>MVX</CE.3>
      </RXA.17>
    </RXA>
    <RXR>
      <RXR.1>
        <CE.1>IM</CE.1>
        <CE.2>IM</CE.2>
        <CE.3>HL70162</CE.3>
        <CE.4>C28161</CE.4>
        <CE.5>IM</CE.5>
        <CE.6>NCIT</CE.6>
      </RXR.1>
    </RXR>
  </VXU_V04.ORDER>
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT Validation: using for-each](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463824/xslt-validation-using-for-each)

Comment: This is not a duplicate but an extension of that same question.  Thanks!

Comment: You're right! My bad - I did not look at it closely enough.

Answer (score 0):

When you look for the EI.x fields, you aren't at the right level yet:

```
<xsl:for-each select="a:ORC">
 <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="count(a:ORC.3)= 0">
        <dil:message type="error">ORC-3 Filler Order Number not found but is required.</dil:message>
     </xsl:when> 
     <xsl:when test="count(a:ORC.3)> 1">
         <dil:message type="error">Only one Filler Order Number (ORC-3) allowed per Order Segment.</dil:message>
     </xsl:when> 
     <xsl:when test="count(a:EI.1)> 1">
         <dil:message type="error">When present, only one Filler Order Number (ORC-3) allowed per Order Segment.</dil:message>
     </xsl:when> 
     <xsl:when test="count(a:EI.1)= 0">
         <dil:message type="error">When Filler Order Number Present, Entity Identifier (ORC-3/EI-1) is required.</dil:message>
     </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="count(a:EI.3)= 0 and count(a:EI.2)= 0">
         <dil:message type="error">When Filler Order Number Present, Namespace ID (ORC-3/EI-2) or Universal ID (ORC-3/EI-3) is required.</dil:message>
     </xsl:when>  
     <xsl:when test="count(a:EI.3)= 1 and count(a:EI.4)= 0">
       <dil:message type="error">When Filler Order Number Universal ID is present, Universal ID Type (ORC-3/EI-4) is required.</dil:message>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="count(a:EI.3)= 0 and count(a:EI.4)= 0">
      <dil:message type="error">When Filler Order Number Universal ID is not present, Universal ID Type (ORC-3/EI-4) is not supported.</dil:message>
     </xsl:when> 
     <xsl:when test="count(a:ORC.3)= 1">
         <dil:message type="info">Value of '<xsl:value-of select="./a:EI.1"/>', '<xsl:value-of select="./a:EI.2"/>', '<xsl:value-of select="./a:EI.3"/>', '<xsl:value-of select="./a:EI.4"/>' found for Filler Order Number (ORC-2).</dil:message>
     </xsl:when>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

you need to add in another level to get to the EI's. You can do this with an extra for-each/select, or by changing the xpath's as follows.

```
<xsl:for-each select="a:ORC">
 <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="count(a:ORC.3)= 0">
        <dil:message type="error">ORC-3 Filler Order Number not found but is required.</dil:message>
     </xsl:when> 
     <xsl:when test="count(a:ORC.3)> 1">
         <dil:message type="error">Only one Filler Order Number (ORC-3) allowed per Order Segment.</dil:message>
     </xsl:when> 
     <xsl:when test="count(a:ORC.3/a:EI.1)> 1">
         <dil:message type="error">When present, only one Filler Order Number (ORC-3) allowed per Order Segment.</dil:message>
     </xsl:when> 
     <xsl:when test="count(a:ORC.3/a:EI.1)= 0">
         <dil:message type="error">When Filler Order Number Present, Entity Identifier (ORC-3/EI-1) is required.</dil:message>
     </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="count(a:ORC.3/a:EI.3)= 0 and count(a:ORC.3/a:EI.2)= 0">
         <dil:message type="error">When Filler Order Number Present, Namespace ID (ORC-3/EI-2) or Universal ID (ORC-3/EI-3) is required.</dil:message>
     </xsl:when>  
     <xsl:when test="count(a:ORC.3/a:EI.3)= 1 and count(a:ORC.3/a:EI.4)= 0">
       <dil:message type="error">When Filler Order Number Universal ID is present, Universal ID Type (ORC-3/EI-4) is required.</dil:message>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="count(a:ORC.3/a:EI.3)= 0 and count(a:ORC.3/a:EI.4)= 0">
      <dil:message type="error">When Filler Order Number Universal ID is not present, Universal ID Type (ORC-3/EI-4) is not supported.</dil:message>
     </xsl:when> 
     <xsl:when test="count(a:ORC.3/a:ORC.3)= 1">
         <dil:message type="info">Value of '<xsl:value-of select="./a:EI.1"/>', '<xsl:value-of select="./a:EI.2"/>', '<xsl:value-of select="./a:EI.3"/>', '<xsl:value-of select="./a:EI.4"/>' found for Filler Order Number (ORC-2).</dil:message>
     </xsl:when>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I see what you are saying.  I ended up adding the statement "<xsl:for-each select="a:ORC/a:ORC.3">" before my first check for an EI field.  I'm not a programmer so I'm not sure if my approach is the best way to do it, but it's working.  Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Yeh, either way would have worked. If there are multiple ORC.3 elements, then what you did is best, makes little difference in the long run. If the answer is correct you should mark it as solved by clicking the Tick next to the appropriate answer (saves other people from answering the same question).